# I have this listbox and want get filter policy type & coverage type

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, multi-select, listboxitem, in-operator

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="chosen-select-single mg-b-20">
        <label style="color: red;">*</label><label>Organization:</label>
        <br />
        <asp:ListBox ID="lst_organization" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_organization_OnSelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv_organization" runat="server" ControlToValidate="lst_organization"
            Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="save" InitialValue="" ErrorMessage="Select Organization" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
</div>
```

To get [Policy type, Coverage Type] as per selected [Organization ID]

```cs
protected void ddl_organization_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        StringBuilder sc = new StringBuilder();

        if (lst_organization.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            if (lst_organization.SelectedIndex != 0 || lst_organization.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                //To get [Policy Type] as per [organization ID] -----
                cam.fill_DDL(ddl_policy_type, "POLICY_TYPE", "POLICY_TYPE_ID", "get_policy_type_as_per_organization",
                    lst_organization.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim(), "", "", "", "", "", "");

                //To get [Coverage Type] as per [organization ID] -----
                cam.fill_DDL(ddl_coverage_type, "COVERAGE_TYPE", "COVERAGE_TYPE_ID", "get_coverage_type_as_per_organization",
                   lst_organization.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim(), "", "", "", "", "", "");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string script = "alert(\"Exception in getting [Policy/Coverage Type] as per selected [Organization] - Insurance Policy Details :'" + ex.Message.ToString() + "'.\");";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Information", script, true);
    }
}
```

```sql
select distinct mct.COVERAGE_TYPE,mct.COVERAGE_TYPE_ID,mo.ORGANIZATION
        from A_COVERAGE_TYPE_ORGANIZATION as acto
        inner join dbo.M_COVERAGE_TYPE as mct on acto.COVERAGE_TYPE_ID=mct.COVERAGE_TYPE_ID
        inner join dbo.M_ORGANIZATION as mo on acto.ORGANIZATION_ID=mo.ORGANIZATION_ID
        inner join dbo.M_DIVISION as md on mo.DIVISION_ID=md.DIVISION_ID
        where acto.ISDELETED='False' and acto.ORGANIZATION_ID=@SEARCH_ID1
        group by mct.COVERAGE_TYPE_ID, mct.COVERAGE_TYPE,mo.ORGANIZATION
        order by mct.COVERAGE_TYPE_ID asc
```

I have a list box for organizations, want to filter policy type and organization assigned to organization.
When I am selecting more than one organization ("1,2,5") it does not show any result . filter is not working. What is missing?

Comment: Why do you have a `GROUP BY` and a `DISTINCT` in the same query scope, when a `GROUP BY` already returns the data in *distinct* groups? However, why are you using a `GROUP BY` when you have no aggregation? Something is certainly wrong with that SQL query.

Comment: Yes I will remove it. You have solution for my problem @Larnu